# what is the event that needed to use for multiselect in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to filter a list of movies based on their categories by selecting them using a select menu (select tag), I could do it with a button using on click event it works, but when I want to replace it buy multi-select by changing the event to onChange the filter didn't work.

what do you think?

Thank you

//filter movies based on their categories, this function is created in App.js, it has been passed as props to my CategoriesFilter components

```
const filterMovie = (category) => {
    const filterMovie = MoviesData.filter((movie)=> movie.category === category);
    setMoviesList(filterMovie);
  }
```

// this my components

```
const CategoriesFilter = ({categories, filterMovie}) => {
    return (
    <div>  

    <select >
    {categories.map((category, index)=> {
        return (
        <option key={index} onChange={()=> filterMovie(category)}>{category}</option>       
        )
    })}
    </select> 

    </div>
      
    )
}
```

Comment: you mentioned multi-select , but don't see anything about it in snippet

Comment: it is the select tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options.

1. You can probably build a custom multi select dropdown component with checkboxes for each item.
2. You can use third party npm packages like react-select. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select

I would suggest you to use the `react-select`.

You can also use select tag with multiple attribute. But it won't work the way you want it to.

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars" multiple>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
```

To select multiple items, you'll have `ctrl` + `click` the items

Answer (score 1):

1. Multiple select is `<select multiple/>`
2. onchange event is not associated with each option, it is an event of select element.